# Insert data sort ascending

Tags: vb.net, sorting, ms-access, vba, insertion-sort

I have a case where I want to insert data to a database with datetime,
when I insert the data into the database, it is not sorted the way I expect it to be.

Here's what I expected
a1
a2
a3
a4
b1
b2
b3
b4

Here's what I get
a1
a2
b1
b2
b3
b4
a3
a4

This my current code on (sharpdevelop) vb language

```
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Journal Entry\Database\jentry_db.mdb;Persist Security Info=False")   
        connection.Open         
            Try
                Dim transaction As OleDbTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction
                Try
                    For Each DetailRowLL As DataRow In DetailsTableLL.Rows
                    Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO T_TransactionsAccrualDetails (AccrualNo, GLAccountID, PCCodeID, JournalClass, [Amount], Description, [DateIn])" & _
                    " VALUES (@AccrualNoParam2LL, @GLAccountIDParam2LL, @PCCodeIDParam2LL, @JournalClassParam2LL, @AmountParam2LL, @DescriptionParam2LL, @DateInParam2LL)", connection, transaction)
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@AccrualNoParam2LL", DetailRowLL.Item("AccrualNo"))
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@GLAccountIDParam2LL", DetailRowLL.Item("GLAccountID"))
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@PCCodeIDParam2LL", DetailRowLL.Item("PCCodeID"))
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@JournalClassParam2LL", DetailRowLL.Item("JournalClass"))
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@AmountParam2LL", DetailRowLL.Item("Amount"))
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@DescriptionParam2LL", DetailRowLL.Item("Description"))
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@DateInParam2LL", DetailRowLL.Item("DateIn"))
                    command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Next
                    transaction.Commit
                    TempTableLL.clear
                
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)   
                    transaction.Rollback
                    Exit Sub
                End Try         
            Finally
                connection.Close
            End Try
                ResetLL()
                MsgBox("Success")
                Exit Sub
              Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)   
              End Try
```

@Tetsuya
This code for inserting to datatable , FYI for masterdata PCCODELL already sort ASC so what I need to change or to do?

```
Me.LL_txtTotalAllocation.Text = Format(CDbl(LL_txtAmount.Text - lngTotal).ToString("N2"))
        strGetAccrualAllocation = Me.LL_txtTotalAllocation.Text
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT PCCODELL.* FROM PCCODELL ORDER BY PCCODELL.PCCodeID ASC", "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Journal Entry\Database\jentry_db.mdb;Persist Security Info=False")
            Dim table As New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(table)
            
            For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                Dim newRow As DataRow = DetailsTableLL.NewRow
                newRow("AccrualNo") = strLLAccrualNo
                newRow("GLAccountID") = "83101002"
                newRow("PCCodeID") =  row("PCCodeID")
                newRow("JournalClass") = "R"
                newRow("Description") = strGetDescriptionLL
                newRow("Amount") = -CDbl(row("PERCENTAGE")) * Double.Parse(strGetAccrualAllocation) 'Format( -1 * CDbl(row("PERCENTAGE") * strGetAccrualAllocation).ToString("N2"))
                newRow("DateIn") = Now.ToString()
                DetailsTableLL.Rows.Add(newRow)
                Thread.Sleep(interval)
            Next
            BindDetailsLL
```

Comment: What you need to do is sorting `DetailsTableLL` based with its order and perform insert with ordered data (I don't know `DetailsTableLL` structure but surely it's a `DataTable` which is selectable).

Comment: Also, don't loop through a `DataTable` and call `ExecuteNonQuery` multiple times. Use a data adapter and call `Update` once to save all the data in one go.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, that's not really good advice because that can't work if you insert data on more than one occasion and the relevant column values overlap. An `ORDER BY` clause should be used when querying if you ant a specific order regardless. Even if the database data is SUPPOSED to be in a particular order, there's no real way to guarantee that it is, whereas using an `ORDER BY` clause when querying is a guarantee that the data you get will be in the order you want.

Comment: for inserting data to datatable and bind to grid its alread sort , the problem is just inserting to database from grid.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, the data will be inserted in the same order as it appears in the `DataTable`. If the data that's inserted is not in the desired order then neither is the data in your `DataTable`. Maybe you have set the `Sort` property of the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable` or a `BindingSource`. In that case, that's what you would loop through to get the data in that order. I can only repeat though, the order in the database should be irrelevant because you should be applying an `ORDER BY` clause when you query anyway. Otherwise, you're doing it wrong.